# Copy tabs of similar partial name to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Would appreciate if there's any help anywhere. Let's say, I have the following tabs: `Data Set 001`, `Data Set 002`, `Data Set 003`, so long the tab names contain **Data Set**, it should copy over to another workbook (let's say `Main File`). Any help with regards to this is welcomed. Thanks all in advance!

Best Regards,
Josh

Comment: Thanks everyone for their contribution! I've actually used @walt tay's code and it worked! Big kudos to this community here :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this in Workbook containing worksheet, "ASSESSMENT FORMxx":

```
Sub CopyWorksheetsToNewWorkbook()

'This macro is to be in the ActiveWorkbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
wb.SaveAs Filename:="Book10" & ".xlsx"
Workbooks.Open ("Book10.xlsx")

For Each ws In Workbooks("ActiveWorkbookName.xlsm").Sheets
If ws.Name Like ("ASSESSMENT FORM*") Then ws.Copy Before:=Workbooks("Book10.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Next ws

Workbooks("Book10.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Move Before:=Workbooks("Book10.xlsx").Sheets(1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Note that both workbook with worksheet "ASSESSMENT FORMxx" and Book10.xlsx must be open.

Comment: Are you just answering your own questions on different accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a go at any code?

```
Sub Whatever()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks("AnyOpenWorkbookName.xlsx")
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name Like "Data Set" & "*" Then
        Call ws.Copy(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all Worksheets of your 1st Workbook, test if its name contains **Data set** with [Worksheet.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.name) and [InStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg264811(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

If the *InStr* function returns something else than 0 (meaning your Worksheet name contains **Data Set**), you can copy the current Worksheet to the 2nd Workbook.

Adapt this sample to your needs:

```
'Loop through all worksheets

If InStr(wsCurrent.Name,"Data Set") <> 0 Then
    ' Copy wsCurrent to new WorkBook
End If

' End of loop
```